# select accuracy to display additional axis breaks

Tags: r, axis-labels

Consider the following problem: `x` is a numeric vector, `pretty(x)` (or `labeling::extended()` etc.) provides pretty breaks, to which I want to manually add some values. Now, `x` can take many forms, say `c(3.20003, 3.20006)` for the sake of example. `pretty()` is pretty smart at finding good breaks for the interval, `3.200030 3.200035 3.200040 3.200045 3.200050 3.200055 3.200060`. Say, I want to add a break at `pi`, how many digits should I round it to, for consistency with the other values? (in this case, `round(pi, 6) = 3.141593`)

I thought of using `nchar`, `plyr::round_any`, but I can't think of a robust method that can handle all cases, including those with scientific formatting (1.3e-4) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

Assuming of course that your plotting function is using `pretty()` (or something that behaves like it) to determine axis breaks, this should provide a general-enough solution:

```
f <- function(x, range) {
    rcol <- floor(log10(abs(diff(pretty(range)[1:2]))))
    round(x, -rcol)
}

## Test it out
options(digits=15)
x <- c(3.20003, 3.20006)

f(pi, x)
# 3.141593

f(pi*1e3, x)
# [1] 3141.592654

f(pi*1e-3, x)
# [1] 0.003142

f(pi*1e10, x*1e10)
# [1] 31415930000

f(pi*1e20, x*1e20)
# [1] 3.141593e+20

f(pi, c(0,5))
# [1] 3

f(pi, c(0,10))
# [1] 3

f(c(pi, -pi), c(-1.2,0.0))
# [1]  3.1 -3.1

f(pi*1e-7, x)
# [1] 0

f(pi*2e-7, x)
# [1] 1e-06
```

Comment: looks good, thanks. I see problems showing up outside the domain of `log10()` though, e.g. `-1.2`, `0.0`.

Comment: @baptiste -- OK, I've fixed that and another problem, simplifying the function a fair bit as well. I think this it's good now.